# Nullable pointer as return value in Vala

Tags: pointers, vala, generic-interface

Imagine we have something like this (it's just an example)

```
public interface Foo : GLib.Object {
    public abstract double *f();
}

public class Toto : GLib.Object, Foo {

    private double i;

    public Toto(double i = 0) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public double *f() {
        return &i;
    }

    public static int main(string[] args) {
        Foo a = new Toto(42.0);
        double i = *a.f();
        stdout.printf("%.3f\n", i);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

this code works perfectly fine, but the problem is that `Foo` must be generic with `public abstract T *f()`, so `Toto` must implement `Foo<double>`, but

> `double' is not a supported generic type argument

(and my first question is "why?", as far as i know i can use int for example without any problem)

so it's `Foo<double?>` and i need something like `double i = (!) *(a.f())`, but it's just doesn't work (at the C level)

> error: invalid use of void expression `i = (gdouble) (*(*_tmp1_));`

so how can i use `f()` method?

(my vala version is 0.36.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use pointers in Vala in the first place? (That is discouraged, pointers are in the language for corner cases.)

A nullable type in Vala is a pointer in the generated C code.

So one way to tackle this is:

```
public interface Foo<T> : GLib.Object {
    public abstract T f();
}

public class Toto : GLib.Object, Foo<double?> {

    private double i;

    public Toto(double i = 0) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public double? f() {
        return i;
    }

    public static int main(string[] args) {
        Foo<double?> a = new Toto(42.0);
        double? i = a.f();
        stdout.printf("%.3f\n", (!) i);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

This compiles and works perfectly fine with valac 0.36.3 here.

The type signature of the generated C function for `Toto.f` is:

```
static gdouble* toto_real_f (Foo* base);
```

Comment: yes of course, I understand that it's not really good idea to use pointers (and I don't use them anymore) now it's more like abstract question. It's true that with `public abstract T f()` everything works, but I wanted to use `public abstract T *f()` for some mystic reason, and in this case it's all getting very confusing. Anyways thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm with you on this one, the Vala generics can be confusing. I'm grateful Vala has them at all, though :).